# jQuery column equal height issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to display two divs with the height set to a 3rd of the body width and match these height if the divs require more space to match one another. like equal height columns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var width = $('body').width();
var thirtyheight = width /10*3
$('.thirtyheight').css('height',thirtyheight);
```

This gets the width and sets as height perfectly, I've tried using equal height snippets with this but nothing yet has worked.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$('.thirtyheight').css({'height',thirtyheight+'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

First calculate 1/3 of the body height and save it in a variable. Then go trough each column and check if it is higher then the calculated height, if `yes` override the variable saved before. Something like this:

```
var c = $("body").height() / 100 * 33.33;
$(".thirtyheight").each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(el).height() > c) { c = $(el).height(); }
}).height(c);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3JdYj/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I've decided to get the parent height to resize the child divs, Works a treat.

```
var colHeight = $(".parent").height();
$('.child').css('min-height',colHeight);
```